# Why does one need accusative after the impersonal construct "es gibt"?

Tags: phrase, accusative

I don't understand the reason why you need accusative instead of nominative after the impersonal construct *es gibt* (or *gibt es* in questions).

According to the analysis of the parts of speech, what comes after it should be the subject of the sentence, not the object, like for instance in:

> Es gibt ein(en) Fehler auf dem Tisch.

Can you clarify the use of accusative here? I can probably deduce that the subject is *es* so that *Fehler* would become an object, but I'd like to have the complete grammatical analysis.

Comment: >pen = Füller/Stift >feather = Feder >mistake = Fehler You may mixed up Feder and Füllfederhalter (fountain pen).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Es gibt einen Fehler auf dem Tisch.

*Es*, although an impersonal is still the subject acting on the object (the mistake). Imagine if in English you said

> It gives a mistake on the table.

the mistake is still being given by the it. On the other hand, if you said

> Es ist ja niemand da.

then it's *niemand* and not *niemanden* because *sein* is a linking verb so both sides of the sentence are nominative (*niemand* is the nominative predicate of *es*, to use fancy terms), and the *es* is not acting on the *niemand*, the *es* is the *niemand* (and the *niemand* is the *es*).

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now! Ooops, I meant to use pen (Feder) instead of Fehler, having an error on the table does not make much sense :P!

Comment: @thekeyofgb, also "ES GIBT + AKK." und "GIBT ES + AKK.", und "ES IST + NOM." und "IST ES + NOM." ?? Danke!

Answer (score 0):

geben is a [Transitive Verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivity_%28grammar%29), the objects need to be inflected as such:

> Etwas gibt <*dem* neuteral*en* dativ*en* Objekt> <*den* maskulin*en* akkusativ*en* Gegenstand>.

As thekeyofgb pointed out, it depends on the [Casus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case#German).

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the sentence:

- **Es**
  Subject in nominative case, third person, singular, neuter
- **gibt**
  Predicate. A transitive verb in present tense, third person, singular (matching with subject in person and number)
- **einen Fehler**
  Accusative object. The mandatory completion of verb. It is that part of speech that makes the verb transitive. It consists of:

  - **einen**
    Article. Indefinite, accusative case, singular, neuter (matching with the noun in case, number and gender)
  - **Fehler**
    Noun. Accusative case, singular, neuter
- **auf dem Tisch**
  prepositional object; an optional completion of the verb. It consists of:

  - **auf**
    local preposition
  - **dem Tisch**
    Dative object, consists of:

    - **dem**
      Article. Definite, dative case, singular, male (matching with the noun in case, number and gender)
    - **Tisch**
      Noun. Dative case, singular, male

---

The sentence is ruled by the predicate, which is a form of »*geben*« (to give). This verb has two mandatory complements:

1. Who is giving?
2. What is given?

Of those two complements, only one is performing the action (*who?*). The other complement is just the thing that is handed over (*what?*). That part, that performs the action, is the sentences subject, and it is **always** this subject, that stands in nominative case.

But if you say in English:

> There is an error on the table.

Who is giving something? This question sounds weird, but since you use the verb *geben* (to give) in German, you have to ask this question. The answer is: Nobody. Nobody is giving anything in fact. Things just **are**, they are in fact not **given**. So you have nothing to place it into the subjects position.

And this exactly the situation where the syntactic expletive "*es*" comes in. When ever you have nothing you can use as Subject, you use "es". You do it English too:

> **Es** regnet.
>   **It** rains.

Nobody is performing the action called "raining", but you need a subject. So you use an syntactic expletive.

---

The other mandatory completion of the verb "geben" is that part, that tells us *what* is given ("an error"). This has to be set in accusative case, so it has to be "*einen Fehler*" in German. It is the verb *geben* that forces its mandatory object to be in accusative case.

The prepositional object is an optional object. A sentence without it would be correct too.

> Es gibt einen Fehler.

In this case it contains the information *where* an error exists:

> Es gibt einen Fehler *auf dem Tisch*.